# Find the square root of a big.Int

Tags: go, bigint

I am required to use big.Ints for my project because the numbers I am working with exceed the int64 limit.

With regular ints, you can square it using:

```
math.Sqrt(value)
```

But I can't work out how to do this, but with big.Ints.

Any help would be appreciated greatly,

Thanks

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Sqrt

Comment: @ain could you answer with an example usage? Thanks

Comment: @MaxCodes I added the example.

Answer (score 2):

Use https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Sqrt given in big.int interface

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    var Str = `10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
    bigInt := &big.Int{}
    value, _ := bigInt.SetString(Str, 10)
    sqrt := bigInt.Sqrt(value)
    fmt.Println(sqrt)
}
```

Output:

```
100000000000000000000000000
```